# Wrong output while running PL/SQL file in sql plus command line

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am a beginner in SQL and was running a PL/SQL file in SQL plus command line however it is showing the message' "SP2-0103: Nothing in SQL buffer to run", and the output from the previous executed PL/SQL file is getting displayed followed by the correct output of the current file. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Did you enable `dbms_output`? Otherwise you won't see the "output" of a PL/SQL procedure (or block)

Comment: Show us exactly what you are doing to run this file. What exactly does a PL/SQL file look like- just an anonymous block?

Comment: Does this help? https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1070135/sp2-0103-nothing-in-sql-buffer-to-run Or this? http://www.orafaq.com/maillist/oracle-l/2002/02/07/1340.htm